# Elasticsearch reply for expired scroll context

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, session-timeout

When using the [Elasticsearch scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-scroll.html) to receive query results that have many matches you must provide a `scroll` time-out amount. Elasticsearch does not guarantee keeping the scroll context alive beyond that time-out (scrolls are processed as a kind of "session" that Elasticsearch remembers).

But what happens if you ask Elasticsearch for another "page" **after that time-out expires**? What response do you get from Elasticsearch? Does it have a distinctive HTTP status code? Or distinctive fields in a JSON response body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response status code is 404.  You also get an error message explaining what happened.

```
{
    "error": {
        "caused_by": {
            "reason": "No search context found for id [35544152]",
            "type": "search_context_missing_exception"
        },
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "index": null,
                "reason": {
                    "reason": "No search context found for id [35544152]",
                    "type": "search_context_missing_exception"
                },
                "shard": -1
            }
        ],
        "grouped": true,
        "phase": "query",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "reason": "No search context found for id [35544152]",
                "type": "search_context_missing_exception"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception"
    },
    "status": 404
}
```